# Laravel many to many multiple primary key with pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

I have a question.

My customer has a database with some tables like this:

**Table A**

> a_id (type uuid, is primary key)
>
> [...]

**Table B**

> b_id (type uuid, is primary key)
>
> [...]

**Table AB**

> a_id (type uuid, is primary key with b_id)
>
> b_id (type uuid, is primary key with a_id)
>
> level (type int)   [...]

The relations between A table and B table is many to many.
This is no problem:

```php
// On model A
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\B', 'App\Models\AB', 'a_id', 'b_id');

// On model B
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\A', 'App\Models\AB', 'b_id', 'a_id');
```

Now I need get **level** from table AB at the same time.

I've tried to add

```php
->withPivot('level');
```

at the end, Something like this:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\A', 'App\Models\AB', 'b_id', 'a_id')->withPivot('level');
```

If I do this, I get not errors, but **level** not appears on pivot.
Only appears **a_id** and **b_id**.

Someone helps me to obtein level??

Comment: did you add withPivot to both models?

Comment: Ouch! (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻... thank you!